# How to Show images in ListView depends on the date

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.4-sydney, livebindings

I'm Using Delphi Sydney 10.4 FMX, I have a ListView connected to a Database with liveBinding, ImageList that has 3 images.

In the ListView, I Have 3 Fields: Image, Expiry, Domain.

The Expiry and Domain are filled from the Database, but the image I want to show depends on the date, example :

Expiry = date of today or before today: I want to show imageindex 0

Expiry = from Tomorrow until 30 days from Today: I want to show imageindex 1

Expiry = 31 Days Later from today: I want to show imageindex 2

```
procedure TForm1.DomainsListViewUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  var DT : TDateTime;
  DT := Now;
  if DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['expiry'].AsString < datetostr(DT+30) then
    DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['image'] := 1
  else if DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['expiry'].AsString < DateToStr(DT) then
    DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['image'] := 0
  else if DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['expiry'].AsString > DateToStr(DT+31) then
    DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex].Data['image'] := 2
end;
```

I used this code, but does not works correctly

Comment: when i remove .asstring i got error :
'E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'TValue''

Comment: why would you remove `.AsString` if your field contains a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `String` values, which doesn't work to compare dates. You should be comparing `TDateTime` values instead, as well as paying more attention to the *order* of your comparisons.

Try something more like this instead:

```
uses
  ..., System.SysUtils, System.DateUtils;

procedure TForm1.DomainsListViewUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
begin
  var Item: TListViewItem := DomainsListView.Items[DomainsListView.ItemIndex]; // or: DomainsListView.Selected
  var dtToday: TDateTime := System.DateUtils.Today;
  var dtExpiry: TDateTime := System.SysUtils.StrToDate(Item.Data['expiry'].AsString);
  if dtExpiry <= dtToday then
    Item.Data['image'] := 0 
  else if dtExpiry < (dtToday+31) then
    Item.Data['image'] := 1
  else
    Item.Data['image'] := 2;
end;
```

Comment: i changed it by System.DateUtils.Today and it works thank you Remy

Comment: this update didn't work:
`E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Data'
E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'StrToDate' that can be called with these arguments`

Comment: @MrSiMo Try declaring `Item` as `TListViewItem` instead of `TListItem`. You can ignore the `StrToDate()` error, it is just a side effect of the 1st error and will go away when the 1st error is fixed.

Comment: the images show perfectly, but I have a problem, when I run: `fdquery.insert; `  i got error :

`'' is not a valide date and time.` 3 times.
how can i solve this problem?

Comment: @MrSiMo Obviously, you have to check your input before converting it. Sounds like the ListView is creating a new item before the  data backing that item is ready. For example, try adding this check before the call to `StrToDate()`: `var sExpiry := Item.Data['expiry'].AsString; if sExpiry = '' then Exit;`